# Can I host Careers ads on my own website?

Tags: support, status-declined, jobs, advertising

There is a Stack Overflow Careers campaign which runs on http://blog.codinghorror.com/
I could not find how such campaign is created. 
Is such campaign limited to privileged users? 
If not campaign then I would at least like to display relevant job opening from Stack Overflow Careers on my site as well, Do I have any option?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This isn't the first time this has been asked for.  I will bring it up in our next weekly meeting and get back to you.

---

EDIT: Update after discussion.

We have decided not to support this for now.  That being said, we would be interested to get some more details about your particular use case.  The ads that show up on external sites currently (codinghorror and joelonsoftware) go through a totally different path and are just randomly chosen, but it is clear that is not what you want.

If it's a job you have posted, we offer a script to embed the apply button for the job on your site which you can find at the bottom of each job listing, and if it's just a tag you want to display jobs for, there is no reason you cannot scrape our site (like indeed does) or use our job feed to regularly update a job list on your site.

Answer (score 6):

It happens to be that that is the blog of Jeff Atwood, one of the founders of StackExchange and the initial trilogy, so he is a very privileged user...

I guess you should contact the SE team to talk about the ads, but it seems to me it is a SE only thing. I have never seen it elsewhere.